# [cc creator]Comparison not working

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I have an array of Nodes 'flags', and I want to set my object's position at the first object in that array, it works and the object actually gets positioned as intended, but when I make the comparison it fails and logs 'NO'.

The line of code that sets the position works, but the comparison fails, what's wrong here?!

```
start: function () {
        this.node.position = this.flags[0].position;
        this.movement();
    },
    movement: function() {
       if (this.node.position == this.flags[0].position) {  // Problem
           console.log("YES");
       }
       else {
           console.log("No");
```

**Update:**

When I do it like this it works:

```
if (this.node.position.x == this.flags[0].position.x) // or position.y
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you write javascript here (and it looks like you do) there're two things you should know:

1. You can't compare objects with `==` out of the box

   ({"a":1} == {"a":1})
   Will return **false** (you may try it yourself in your browser.
   As a workaround you could do something like:

   function posCompare(p1, p2){
      return p1.x === p2.x && p1.y === p2.y;
   }

Then use it instead of `==` for positions

2. See how I use `===` instead of `==`? Second thing to know is Use only `===`. You can learn the difference [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) but I'd keep away from `==` anywhere. It's slower, it may cause strange errors here and there - just don't use it at all

Comment: Wait a sec. You wrote comparing position.x-es works (which is inaccurate because you need to check both coordinates) What makes you think 'if (this.node.position.x === this.flags[0].position.x && this.node.position.y == this.flags[0].position.y)' won't work? (perhaps the values are actually different??)

Comment: I was talking about === rather than ==, but yeah, your way works, but I don't understand why my original code will not work, it's massive hassle to keep comparing both x && y like that. In other game engines the position comparison works fine.

Comment: As I've stated there's no build-in comparison of objects in javascript. You can import a js-library just for that if you want to, or perhaps define a function for equality check, but sadly that's just how the things are.